# Bootstrap accordion doesn't always collapse on Google Maps listener event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap-3, mouseevent

How do you get the Bootstrap accordion to show (i.e. smoothly "unroll" itself) only when pointer hovers over a Google map, and hide (i.e. smoothly "collapse" itself) when it leaves the map?

I attach the `.collapse('show')` to `mousemove` event, and `.collapse('hide')` to `mouseout`, but this works only when the pointer **slowly** enters or exits the map. When the motion is rapid (like swiping very quickly across the map), then the accordion stays shown about 50% of the time.

Here's the complete code that shows what I mean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <style>
      #map-canvas {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.816175, 15.966154),
          zoom: 17
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(){
          $('#acc').collapse('show');
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseout', function(){
          $('#acc').collapse('hide');
        });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="acc" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <h1>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

1. You didn't use the appropriate events. `mousemove` fires any time when you move the mouse on the map, and `mouseout` fires also when you hover e.g. the map-controls or the google-logo/copyrights. You better use the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`-events of the map-container
2. When you move the mouse fast in and out there is a conflict between the transitions, you start a new animation while another animation is still running.
   I didn't find an option to stop a running animation with bootstrap, so I would suggest to use jQuery's `slideUp`/`slideDown` instead. The effect will be the same, but jQuery has a method to stop a running animation: `$.stop()`

---

Changes to implement:

1) Remove Bootstrap accordion class, since there doesn't seem to be a way to stop the roll/unroll animation (note that initially the content is hidden using the `display:none` style):

```
<div id="acc" style="display: none;">
  <h1>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
</div>
```

2) Replace **"unroll"** event handler with either,

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map.getDiv(), 'mouseenter', function(){
     $('#acc').stop().slideDown('slow');
});
```

or

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseover', function(){
    $('#acc').stop().slideDown('slow');
});
```

3) Replace the **"roll-up"** event handler with:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map.getDiv(), 'mouseleave', function(){
     $('#acc').stop().slideUp('slow');
});
```

Comment: Thx it works perfectly now, I added the optional "unroll" event handler.

Answer (score 0):

This JQuery-based approach seems to work more smoothly with rapid mouse movements.

```
$( "#map-canvas" ).hover(
  function() { 
    $('#acc').show();
  }, function() {
    $('#acc').hide();
  });
```

[Javascript.info](http://javascript.info/tutorial/mouse-events) says that "Mousemove and mouseover/mouseout trigger when browser internal timing allows."  Perhaps this has something to do with the efficiency.

Comment: Nah, that just instantly hides the element, whereas I'm looking to smoothly collapse the accordion. I.e. ``$('#acc').hide()`` is not the same as ``$('#acc').collapse('hide')``. And btw, the event does indeed trigger, so that's not the problem.